# How to find out what values are accepted for every possible attribute of a given tkinter widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I can get a complete list of attributes for any given tkinter widget with the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk

widget = tk.Button()     # Choose your widget here

for attr in widget.config().keys():
    print(attr)
```

However, I need to find out what possible values can be given for all of these attributes. Is there a similar way to find this?

Comment: Tkinter *doesn't know* what the valid values are.  It just passes on whatever value give it, to the underlying Tcl/Tk interpreter, and reports any error that might be generated thereby.

Answer (score 0):

This function will return attribute names and values for tkinter object `o`. It also filters the shorthand `bd`, `bg` and `fg` since these are duplicates of full names for `border`, `background` and `foreground`.

```py
import tkinter as tk

def get_config(o):
    s = f"{o.__class__.__name__}\n"
    s += "\n".join(f"    {k} = '{v[~0]}'" for k, v in o.config().items() if k not in ['bg', 'fg', 'bd'])
    return s

app = tk.Tk()
print(get_config(app))
```

Comment: OP asks how to *"find out what possible values can be given for all of these attributes"*, for example possible values for `anchor` option are "n", "s", "e", "w", etc.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I need to find out what possible values can be given for all of these attributes. Is there a similar way to find this?

No, there is not. Tkinter and the underlying tk library don't provide that level of introspection.